# recvfrom failing with error 11

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I am trying out a udpclient program which uses **sendto** and **recvfrom** functions. I am setting **SO_RCVTIMEO** value as 10 seconds for my socket.

I am binding the socket to source ipaddress and sourceport. When I check the netstat I can see that there is no other process which is binded with the same values. My bind operation is also successfull.

Then I am doing a sendto which is sending a echo request to destination. After sendto I am doing a recvfrom. But recvfrom fail's saying ERRNO 11 which means **try again** :(

But if I check the wireshark logs I can see ECHO REQUEST and ECHO REPLY which is coming within few milliseconds but still recvfrom is not able to read it :(. In wireshark I am seeing the UDP ECHO REQUEST AND UDP ECHO REPLY.

I dont have any FIREWALL enabled in my system.

Is there any way to debug this issue :( I am really doubting the RECV operation is there any way to find out if the packet is being sent to my sockFD or not ???

**UPDATE1:** My linux PC is connected to another linux pc acting as a server via switch.

Comment: So you see in Wireshark a UDP packet "ECHO REPLY" to a port where your socket is bound to? "ECHO REPLY" somehow looks a bit like ICMP.

You are not so detailed on your setup description. Does your udpclient use the same port for sendto and recvfrom? If not, check port number (endianess). Did you check the success of bind()? Is your client port already used by another program (see: netstat)?

Regarding your "SO_REUSEPORT on linux" question, usually one receiv socket gets the packet.

Comment: HI Harper thanks for the reply .. YES i am getting ECHO reply for the same port to which my socket is bound. YES bind returns successfull and I am seeing the instance using netstat command. My client port is not used by nay other than my application.

Comment: Have you tried netcat (`nc`) to see if you can talk between the machines?

Comment: Does the call return immediately or after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

I have the found out the ISSUE atlast ...

Seems UDP checksum of the packet is wrong as a result IP STACK is dropping the packet before it reach's SOCKET :( as a result recvfrom is getting timeout and coming out.

Answer (score 1):

`EAGAIN` from `recvfrom()` implies one of three things:

- The socket has been set to non-blocking; or
- The `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag was used; or
- The receive timeout has expired.

It sounds like your socket is non-blocking to me.

Comment: He's saying the `SO_RCVTIMEO` is set.

Comment: @Nikolai: Sure, but he's also saying that the reply is coming back well within the `SO_RCVTIMEO` time.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see that in the question.

Comment: @Nikolai: *"and ECHO REPLY which is coming within few milliseconds but still recvfrom is not able to read it"*

Comment: Exactly - there's a packet on the wire but the app is not seeing it.

Comment: @Nikolai: The OP has not said whether it's returning `EAGAIN` immediately (which would imply that it is a nonblocking socket) or after 10 seconds (which would imply that it is not seeing the packet).

Comment: I read it as the former, though yes, not enough info, no point in arguing.

Comment: Hi guys ... after hours going through the flow .. I found that packet is getting dropped by IP STACK as a result my SOCKET is not able to get any of the packets destined to it.

Comment: Just curious - was the socket non-blocking?